# MySQL syntax error 1064 with INSERT statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm getting a MySQL syntax error (1064) using this query. I've been scouring the dozens of mysql syntax questions on SO, googling like mad, and staring at this SQL statement to no avail. Before executing the statement, I am using mysqli's real_escape_string(). I have tried (in my desperation) removing all newlines from the query, but this doesn't help. What's causing the error?

```
INSERT INTO `file_upload`.`files` (
    `id`,
    `name`,
    `user_id`
) 
VALUES (
    NULL,
    'filename.txt',
    1
)
```

The error that I'm getting has the message:

> ...check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'filename.txt\',1)' at line 1

EDIT

Here is the PHP code. Connection is a mysqli object.

```
public function add_file_to_user($file, $user_id) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `file_upload`.`files` (`id`,`name`,`user_id`) VALUES (NULL,'$file->name',$user_id)";
    $res = $this->query($query);
    die($this->connection->errno . $this->connection->error);
}

private function query($str) {
    $str = $this->connection->real_escape_string($str);
    return $this->connection->query($str);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the PHP code you're using, too, please?

Comment: And you're only using `real_escape_string()` on the parameters and not on the string as a whole, aren't you?

Comment: Why do you have a single quote here? `(NULL,'$file->name,$user_id)`

Comment: @le_garry, sorry, I did that in my haste to post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
private function query($str) {
    $str = $this->connection->real_escape_string($str);
    return $this->connection->query($str);
}
```

You're escaping your whole query; you just need escape the variables that you're passing in to it.

```
public function add_file_to_user($file, $user_id) {
    $filename = $this->connection->real_escape_string($file->name);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `file_upload`.`files` (`id`,`name`,`user_id`) VALUES (NULL,'$filename',$user_id)";
    $res = $this->query($query);
}

private function query($str) {
    return $this->connection->query($str);
}
```

(Though I've not tested it to see if it works)

Comment: that's it. Thanks. I'll accept the answer in a second.

Comment: You're welcome - glad to have helped. You should also look into using bound parameters for your queries - they let you avoid escaping variables, and are much more secure.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you seem to overescape at some point. Check the code, this is *not* the query you're executing.

I suspect, that instead of escaping the string, you escape your whole query.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your error (`'\'filename.txt\',1)'`), it appears the single quotes around the filename are being escaped causing this error to be thrown. It appears you may be escaping your `INSERT` query.

Comment: So is the one before. I think you misinterpret the `'` *before* the the first backslash — it's just the fragment of query quoted.

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO `file_upload`.`files` (`id`,`name`,`user_id`) VALUES (NULL,'$file->name',$user_id)";
```

or

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO `file_upload`.`files` (`id`,`name`,`user_id`) VALUES (NULL,'$file->name','$user_id')";
```